# Import google api fonts in react with "preload" attribute

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts, google-api-js-client

I am currently trying to import google fonts inside of react using the link tag.

If I change the attribute "rel" to "stylesheet" and delete the "as" attribute it works, however using "preload" doesn't import the fonts properly. The texts inside both "divs" have the same fonts. I get no error messages in the terminal.

Why is that so and how can i make it work?

https://jsfiddle.net/ctLgmd2f/13/

or

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>
        <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Baloo+Bhaijaan|Roboto:300,400,500"
    rel="preload"
    as="style"/>
                <div style={{fontFamily: "Roboto"}}>The fonts shouldnt match!</div>
                <div>The fonts shouldnt match!</div>
           </div>);
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: The point of `preload` is to load the URL without actually applying it.

Comment: Looks like I lack some basic understanding of those tags. I thought preload meant that it loads the fonts before anything else.

Comment: This is a useful article explaining how to preload a Google Font: https://ashton.codes/preload-google-fonts-using-resource-hints/ After the link element with preload, put your regular style sheet link.